# Java: new instance of the same type as the ArrayList loop stops the loop

Tags: java, arraylist, instantiation

The loop in the following code stops after the first element:

```
public ArrayList<Position> moveOptions(Player p, Die d)
    {
        // Init array
        ArrayList<Position> options = new ArrayList<>();
        Helper.m("Option size: " + options.size());
        // Get player's pin positions (current)
        ArrayList<Position> pos = p.getPinPositions();
        Helper.m("p.getPinPositions() size: " + pos.size());
        int i = 0;

        for (Position ps : p.getPinPositions()) {
            Helper.m("I am in the loop");
            // Get the pin in this position
            Pin pin = ps.getPin();
            // Get next field according to the die
            Helper.m("The size of pos before 'next' call:" + pos.size());
            Field next = ps.getPin().getNextFieldByDie(d);
            Helper.m("The size of pos after 'next' call:" + pos.size());
            // If the die value doesn't exceed the board size
            if(next != null)
            {
                Helper.m("next is not null");
                Helper.m("The size of pos before constructor call:" + pos.size());
                Position possible = new Position(next, ps.getPin());
                Helper.m("The size of pos after constructor call:" + pos.size());
                options.add(possible);
            }
            Helper.m("The size of 'options' is now " + options.size());
            i++;
        }

        Helper.m("I: " + i);
        Helper.m("The final size of 'options' is " + options.size());
        Helper.m("The final size of 'pos' is " + pos.size());
        return options;
    }
```

After some investigation I got to the conclusion that this line is the issue:

```
Position possible = new Position(next, ps.getPin());
```

The loop doesn't continue even if I put a 'continue' there or if I create a new empty instance of the Position outside the loop. Any suggestions?

The output is this:

```
Option size: 0
p.getPinPositions() size: 4
I am in the loop
The size of pos before 'next' call:4
The size of pos after 'next' call:1
next is not null
The size of pos before constructor call:1
The size of pos after constructor call:1
The size of 'options' is now 1
I: 1
The final size of 'options' is 1
The final size of 'pos' is 1
```

The Position class:

```
/**
 * Keep pin positions in object
 */
public class Position {
    // Field object
    private Field field;
    // Pin Object
    private Pin pin;

    public Position(){};
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param f Field object
     * @param p Pin Object
     */
    public Position(Field f, Pin p)
    {
        this.setFeild(f);
        this.setPin(p);
    }

    /**
     * Field setter
     * @param f 
     */
    public final void setFeild(Field f)
    {
        this.field = f;
    }
    /**
     * Field getter
     * @return 
     */
    public Field getField()
    {
        return this.field;
    }
    /**
     * Pin setter
     * @param p 
     */
    public final void setPin(Pin p)
    {
        this.pin = p;
    }
    /**
     * Pin getter
     * @return 
     */
    public Pin getPin()
    {
        return this.pin;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: how did you arrive at conclusion that `Position possible = new Position(next, ps.getPin());` line is the issue?

Comment: Probably won't fix your problem, but you can change your call to `ps.getPin()` to just `pin` in the line `Position possible = new Position(next, ps.getPin());` assuming nothing else you call makes a change to the value that you care about.

Comment: Do you have a constructor in the `Position` class that looks something like this : `public Position(Field f, Pin p){ ... }`

Comment: @codeMan if i remove that line, the loops goes just fine

Comment: @Sam it was like that at the beginning, but it went to what is it right now due to debugging

Comment: @codeMan Yes, i do have that kind of a constructor

Comment: By stop, do you mean it just "sticks" inside the loop, it throws an exception, or it just iterates once then continues outside the loop?

Comment: It continues outside the loop, I get no errors/exceptions

Comment: I think we might need to see the constructor for `Position`

Comment: @Sam constructor added into question

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you ;) Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) we can reproduce?

Comment: Can you also output the size of the list after the for loop?

Comment: You could always try a clean and re-compile. Otherwise, it sounds like your `Position` class has a reference back to `Person` and the methods `setField()` and `setPin()` are modifying the original list. Since everything in Java that is an `Object` is a reference, you are actually modifying the list you are iterating through, but even this should cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @m0skit0 I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Sam I updated the question at 'The output is' part (added some prints in the code).

Comment: With the final size of `pos` being 1, I am now *definitely* suspicious that your constructor and associated methods are capable of modifying the list of `Positions` contained in your `Player` class. In an attempt to move towards the SSCCE proposed by @m0skit0 (except maybe for the small part), can you post the code for `setField()` and `setPin()`?

Comment: I see a statement that says `Helper.m("Positions size: " + pos.size());` but I don't see an output line that matches this.

Comment: @Sam question updated with the entire ''Position'' class

Comment: @ajb updated the question (it was an after posting string change)

Comment: Could you also print out the size of `pos` before and after your `Position` constructor call, and before and after `Field next = ps.getPin().getNextFieldByDie(d);`?

Comment: @Sam question updated, and it appears that somehow 'next' changes the size of pos ....

Comment: Voila! the problem actually occurs in `Field next = ps.getPin().getNextFieldByDie(d);` Once again, this is likely because either `Pin` or `Die` has a reference to your `Person` object. Seeing the code for these classes will help us answer your question

Comment: @Sam please see this repository: https://bitbucket.org/mvlasceanu/programming-workshop-ludo-game/src/06dfc0eaa5b5c0f5ac436768ace8a07c6e2f67ab/src/dk/itu/pw/ludo/ludoboard/?at=master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused in your `Pin` class in your `getCurrentField()` method which is called when you call `getNextFieldByDie(Die die)` from your loop. The problem is that you are removing items from the iterator that are not equivalent to the current pin. This action doesn't just produce an `ArrayList` with the elements you are interested in, it actually modifies the backing store which in your code is in the `GameManager` class.

```
public Field getCurrentField()
{
    ArrayList<Position> positions = this.getManager().getPinPositions();

    for (Iterator<Position> it=positions.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if (!it.next().getPin().equals(this))
            it.remove();
    }

    if(positions.size() > 0)
        return positions.get(0).getField();
    else
        return null;
}
```

After calling `it.remove()` on the `Position` objects that meet your criteria, your `pos` list (which is drawn from the same instance of the `GameManager` class) will no longer have anything but the original item left in it. Hence the change of size.

Rather than removing items from the iterator, it would be better to create a new `ArrayList` that contained the elements of interest.

```
public Field getCurrentField()
{
    ArrayList<Position> positions = this.getManager().getPinPositions();
    //Just create a new list
    ArrayList<Position> matchedPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
    //Use the for-each syntax to iterate over the iterator
    for (Position position : positions) {
        //switch the logic and add to the new list
        if (position.getPin().equals(this))
            matchedPositions.add(position);
    }

    if(matchedPositions.size() > 0)
        return matchedPositions.get(0).getField();
    else
        return null;
}
```

I also want to point out that you have this same pattern occurring in multiple places in the code base you posted, and **all** of them could cause similar problems and should likely be switched.

It also just happens that you were using the **only** method for modifying a list while iterating over that list that will not throw the `ConcurrentModificationException` making it harder to detect that a change had been made in your original list.

Comment: That solved the issue. I used the 'Iterator' without knowing the entire story about it. Thank you for your time! I will fix these everywhere.